# PHP PEAR BBCodeParser2 throws error whenever I change folder path

Tags: php, pear

I downloaded the PEAR Package HTML_BBCodeParser2 and tried it satisfactorily in easyPHP (LAMP) root folder.

I am using:

```
require_once('HTML/BBCodeParser2.php');

/* get options from the ini file */
$config = parse_ini_file('BBCodeParser2.ini', true);
$options = $config['HTML_BBCodeParser2'];
$parser = new HTML_BBCodeParser2($options);
```

Everything works fine and the BBCode gets parsed well. But if I transfer the 'HTML' folder containing BBCodeParser2.php to anyother folder and change the required path then it throws the following error:

```
Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Failed to load filter Basic' in ........ ...... HTML_BBCodeParser2-0.1.0\B\HTML\BBCodeParser2.php on line 190
```

I do understand that line `188 to 190`in BBCodeParser2.php is:

```
@include_once 'HTML/BBCodeParser2/Filter/'.$filter.'.php';
  if (!class_exists($class)) {
   throw new InvalidArgumentException("Failed to load filter $filter");
```

I tried every path relative+absolute but, either the page throws the above error or just doesn't show anything.

My question is that, if I have to make new folder say `B` and move the files in this what should I change at `line 188` to be as I know that it's that line which throws the error.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: remove the error suppression operator beofre the include (`@`)

Comment: Thanks ... now I got the errors and it seems like I need to change the Path address in every file (Filters) ....Thanks the error reporting might solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Do not mess with the paths in the files - it will prevent you from upgrading the lib to newer versions.

If you want to move the complete library to another directory, you need to adjust the include path as well.

Comment: But if I do not change the path(all files + include path) then I will need to put the file in everyfolder where I need the BBCode Parser (4 folders)...!
As for upgrading the lib (correct me if I am wrong) I think PEAR anyways does not tell about the updates automatically , I need to check personally from their website

Comment: you only have to adjust your include path, nothing more.

Comment: Thank you but it does not work with changing only the include...the other files (filters) start to throw errors